# SQL query split long string formed by pairs

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need help with SQL query. I have table:

| LineID | PointAxis |
| --- | --- |
| 25 | `[(2,4), (3,5), (7,13)]` |
| 26 | `[(3,6),(4,8)]` |
| 27 | `[(4,5), (5,6), (6,7), (7,8)]` |

For example:

```
LineID: 25 PointAxis: [(x1,y1), (x2,y2),(x3,y3)]
```

I would like to split in my SQL query (for other purposes like plotting curves etc.) and it would be best if the result of the query was probably this:

| LineID | PointAxis | x | y | x2 | y2 | x3 | y3 | x4 | y4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | `[(2,4), (3,5), (7,13)]` | 2 | 4 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 13 | NULL | NULL |
| 26 | `[(3,6),(4,8)]` | 3 | 6 | 4 | 8 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 27 | `[(4,5), (5,6), (6,7), (7,8)]` | 4 | 5 | 5 | 6 | 6 | 7 | 7 | 8 |

EDIT:
I tried to split the string using substring and charindex. But I would have to define all the variants / lengths of the strings which is quite complicated. Wouldn't it be smarter?

```
  SELECT [LineID]
    ,Substring (PointAxis, Charindex( '(', PointAxis) + 1,  
Charindex(',',PointAxis)-3) AS [x] FROM [table] t
```

Even such an output would be good:

| LineID | PointAxis | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | `[(2,4), (3,5), (7,13)]` | 2 | 4 |
| 25 | `[(2,4), (3,5), (7,13)]` | 3 | 5 |
| 25 | `[(2,4), (3,5), (7,13)]` | 7 | 13 |

Comment: Hi i think you have multiple way todo this have you try something ? please share what your're trying... loking at : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/spatial-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15 or other solution with https://codingsight.com/t-sql-regular-expressions-substring-patindex-and-charindex/

Comment: What if you have a row with 1000 points? Does the result become 2000 column wide?

Comment: @SalmanA This is exactly the thing I also have a problem with ... I don't know how to ensure this dynamically.

Comment: @cesc then you'll write some application that expects arbitrary number of columns from a query. Why not use the application to parse the data and plot it accordingly.

Comment: What about getting it as rows not columns, pairs of `x,y`? That is much easier

Comment: @Charlieface It would probably also be a satisfactory solution. But how to cut a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can split up each row by first replacing `),` with `|` then splitting on `|`.**

We can then use `CHARINDEX` to find the remaining `,`, and with some more trimming we can get the `x` and `y`

```sql
SELECT
    t.LineID,
    PointID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.LineID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)),
    x = RTRIM(LEFT(v1.value, v2.comma - 1)),
    y = LTRIM(SUBSTRING(v1.value, v2.comma + 1, LEN(v1.value)))
FROM YourTable t
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(t.PointAxis, '),', '|'), '|') s
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (
    REPLACE(
      REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
          REPLACE(
            REPLACE(s.value, '[', ''),
          ']', ''),
        '(', ''),
      ')', ''),
    ' ', '')
) ) v1(value)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (
    CHARINDEX(',', v1.value)
) ) v2(comma)
WHERE v2.comma <> 0;
```

[db<>fiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b72acd993db7e4d3f46b96accce3fd97)

Comment: How can I replace TRIM for functionality in SQL Server 2016? Thx

Comment: You can change it for a bunch of `REPLACE` calls

Comment: @Charlieface The OP did not tell if the sort order is important. I'd use `STRING_SPLIT()` in cases only where I know for sure, that it does not... Btw: I'd imply JSON for this, see my answer if interested.

Answer (score 2):

With v2016 you might use a little help of JSON:

```
declare @v nvarchar(100)=N'[(2,4), (3,5), (7,13)]';

SELECT A.[key] AS Position
      ,JSON_VALUE(A.[value],N'$[0]') AS X
      ,JSON_VALUE(A.[value],N'$[1]') AS Y
FROM OPENJSON(REPLACE(REPLACE(@v,N'(',N'['),N')',N']')) A
```

The idea in short:

- We replace the `()` with `[]` transforming your string into a JSON-array, where each element is a JSON-array itself.
- Now we can use `OPENJSON` to dive into the surrounding array.
- The `key` returns the position in the array
- `JSON_VALUE` allows to fetch each item of an array by its position.

Starting with v2017 you might use `TRANSLATE` instead of `REPLACE`

```
FROM OPENJSON(TRANSLATE(@v,N'()',N'[]')) A
```

**UPDATE for tabular input**

Try this

```
DECLARE @dummyTable TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, LineCoords VARCHAR(1000));
INSERT INTO @dummyTable VALUES('[(2,4), (3,5), (7,13)]')
                             ,('[(3,6),(4,8)]')
                             ,('[(4,5), (5,6), (6,7), (7,8)]'); 

SELECT t.ID
      ,A.[key] AS Position
      ,JSON_VALUE(A.[value],N'$[0]') AS X
      ,JSON_VALUE(A.[value],N'$[1]') AS Y
FROM @dummyTable t
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(REPLACE(REPLACE(t.LineCoords,N'(',N'['),N')',N']')) A
```

Comment: Thank you, that sounds very interesting. I'm just not sure how to use it in my case without having to declare the values at first, but the whole column.

Comment: @Cesc just use `outer apply openjson(.... ` and your column instead of the variable.

Comment: Okej something like this if I understand correctly? `FROM table outer apply openjson (REPLACE(REPLACE(COLUMN,N'(',N'['),N')',N']')) A`

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Could you show an example of a fiddle?